# I can't get my Magnific popup to load on page load

Tags: javascript, html, popup, pageload, magnific-popup

first of all, I know this question is already discussed in other places on this website. I've read them all but can't get my code to work.. My javascript skills are rather limited so it would be great ifsomeone could help me with this one.

I got the popup to show with animations and it works great. But I still have to click the link to show the popup. I want to load the popup when the page loads. I've seen code for this but I can't get it to work properly.

This is my code:

```
<a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog" >Open with fade-zoom animation</a><br/>

  <div id="small-dialog" class="zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide">
     -- some content ---
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
      type: 'inline',

      fixedContentPos: true,
      fixedBgPos: true,

      overflowY: 'auto',

      closeBtnInside: true,
      preloader: false,

      midClick: true,
      removalDelay: 300,
      mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Anyone who can tell me how I need to change this code to fire the popup on page load?

Thanks in advance!

Senne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is you're binding a click event on `#popup-with-zoom-anim` that's why it's not triggering on load. You must call the magnificpopup `open` method to open it onload.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items:{
            src: '#small-dialog',
            type: 'inline'
        },
        fixedContentPos: true,
        fixedBgPos: true,
        overflowY: 'auto',
        closeBtnInside: true,
        preloader: false,
        midClick: true,
        removalDelay: 300,
        mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, it works! Do you maybe know how I can delay it a few seconds?

Comment: you can probably try adding it inside settimeout. `setTimeout(function(){ /* insert the function here */ }, 3000);`

Answer (score 1):

If you visit the documentation 
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#initializing-popup
you can see that you have an open option:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    src: 'some-image.jpg'
  },
  type: 'image'
});
```

Since what you want is to open html that is located in your html, you should set type as inline. Example (with button):

```
// From an element with ID #popup
$('button').magnificPopup({
  items: {
      src: '#popup',
      type: 'inline'
  }
});
```

So finally you should have something like this:

```
<div>
<a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog" >Open with fade-zoom animation</a><br/>

  <div id="small-dialog" class="zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide">
     -- some content ---
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.magnificPopup.open({
      src: '#small-dialog',
      type: 'inline'
    });
});
</script>
```

I have not tested it but I hope it can helps.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks I have my solution!